# How can I right-align the text of a Google Adsense ad?

Tags: adsense, text-align

I'm displaying a Google Adsense ad in my site's side menu. Since all menu items are right-aligned, the left-aligned text in the ad looks really wrong. How can I make the text within the ad align to the right as well? I've already tried css ( .adsbygoogle { text-align:right } ), but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Do I have to use Javascript for this to work?

Comment: show the issue in snippet/fiddle, so that easy to find an solution.

Comment: A snippet of a Google ad? Isn't that like asking an astronomy question and being asked to post a picture of the sun?